# Angular Get Parameter from Url with Special Character

Tags: angular, url, routes

my routing is

```
{
                path: 'purchase/:discountCode',
                component: PurchaseComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'purchase/:msg',
                component: PurchaseComponent,
            },
```

my input url is

```
www.example.com/purchase?msg='test message'
or
www.example.com/purchase?discountCode=1111111
```

i want to get msg or discount code

```
  this.routerParmsSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params['discountCode']) {
        //save discountCode

      } else if (params['msg']) {
    //save msg
      }
```

but only when my url is

```
   www.example.com/purchase;msg='test message'
    or
    www.example.com/purchase;discountCode=1111111
```

> can get parameter  instead ? is ;

and when input url is

```
www.example.com/purchase/1111111
```

routing to discountCode

my angular version is 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like that

```
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute){}
dicountCode:string;

ngOnInit(){
    this.dicountCode = this.route.snapshot.params['dicountCode'];
}
```

If you want to access query params you can do it in the following way

```
this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('dicountCode');
```